# How do I remove a singularity that appears when I make a fit to my data?

Tags: fitting, singularity

I am trying to fit a complex algebraic function to a data set [Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mAr4hzQZkqAlRgOPqlqXMPGL49HENAml/view?usp=sharing), which is basically a Lorentzian. The problem I am facing that while fitting there exists an infinity. Could you help me to get rid of infinity?

Since my code is more than 30000 characters (as the algebraic function is very big), I cannot post the code here, so I have put the code on google drive, which can be found here [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_r_IuuxJbAUnnTyNRuF7Pzb2cXj_xgJo/view?usp=sharing).

I have also tried plotting the function, the function was defined as
num[Q_, k0_, F_, [Eta]*, [Omega]*, [Alpha]*, [Omega]0*] := algebraic function
and the plotting was done as
Plot[num[17327, 3.2616, 10^-11, 3.3*10^8, [Omega], 1.23*10^17, 20268509.9], {[Omega], 0, 20273800}, PlotRange -> Automatic]

but I am only getting half part of the plot, please see the attached image file[image]

Comment: An infinity in the data itself, or a computed infinity reported by whatever code you run (which code you should probably include)?

Comment: @Micheal- Infinity by the code, Code I cannot include as it has more than 30000 characters (as the function is very complex) so I have attached a file called code

Comment: Sorry about that: I misread.  Unfortunately, I've gotten used to questions being stated loosely and did not notice that the data and code were actually separate links.  You could try `data = SetPrecision[data, 16]` (or higher than 16) and set `WorkingPrecision ->16` or higher; see if the problem goes away. I don't have time right now to track down a problem in 30000+ characters of code.

Comment: @ Micheal, I tried that it did not work. You do not have to worry about the code as it is just an algebraic solution, which I copied and pasted from Mathematica only. Probably there will be no error.

Comment: Rather than figure out what `NonlinearModelFit` is doing, I think you should first concentrate on plotting the function.  Executing the following `Plot[f /. \[Eta] -> 2.5 10^8, {\[Omega], xmin, xmax}]` (with `f` being your function) and $\eta$ set to the starting value results in a line segment much too low to be even close to what you want.  So either there is a whole lot of round off error or there's something wrong with the function.  Also, if you give the error/warning message that tells you there's an "Infinity by the code", that would be helpful.

Comment: @JimB I tried plotting also. A function was defined num[Q_, k0_, F_, \[Eta]_, \[Omega]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Omega]0_] := algebric function and then plotting was done as Plot[num[17327, 3.2616, 10^-11, 3.3*10^8, \[Omega], 1.23*10^17, 
  20268509.9], {\[Omega], 0, 20273800}, PlotRange -> Automatic]. I am getting half part of the plot, it is not showing me any value after the curve hits infinity

Comment: Including the plot would be helpful to demonstrate what you mean by "infinity in the code".  I'll try the plot you gave.

Comment: @JimB, Sorry about that, I have attached an image file  in the question

Comment: The image can be included in the question.  (There's an "insert picture" option when you edit the question.)  But plotting the function over the range of your data just produces a straight line for values of $\omega$ between the minimum and maximum of your data for values for $\eta$ between 10^6 to 10^10.

Comment: @JimB sorry I did not make myself clear, I have already attached an image of the plot in the question. I am using the constant value of η  (3.3*10^8) and I am varying the value of ω from 0 to  20268509.9.

Comment: I don't see an infinity issue.  Plugging in the maximum value in the data for $\omega$ gets you `num[17327, 3.2616, 10^-11, 3.3*10^8, \[Omega]Max, 1.23*10^17, 20268509.9] = 4.89644*10^-10`.  Try the plot command you gave with `PlotRange->All` rather than `PlotRange->Automatic`.

Comment: @JimB, OK I understood now, what you are trying to say. I tried PlotRange->All also but with no success, the results are the same. I have posted the full code in the chat, if you may wanna look at it.

Comment: Recommend you scale down the function and/or the data to the point in which Fit works then begin building it back up piece-wise to identify any issue.